# sjaakp/yii2-illustrated-behavior Yii2 extension for image not being saved

Tags: yii2

When I click the submit button of the form it is sending an ajax request to the server but it's not saving the Image file return the string 'ajax request'; here is my code in the controller (what am I missing in the action so that it saves the image because I thought by calling save on the model it will save automatically) : :

```
public function actionphoto(){`enter code here`
     $model = Profile::findOne(Yii::$app->user->identity->getId());
     $model->scenario='photo';
     if(\Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->save()){
        var_dump('Image Save');
     }

          if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
              var_dump('ajax request');
              \yii::$app->end();
              return $this->renderAjax('photo',array('model'=>$model));
          }else{
              return $this->render('photo',array('model'=>$model));
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try save with parameter false  this way

```
if(\Yii::$app->request->post() ){
    $model->save(false)
    var_dump('Image Save');
}
```

If the record is inserted in database, mean you have same problem with validation rule (then you can comment the rule selectively for find the probelmatic rule)

Comment: thanks; It is return  var_dump('Image Save') but I went in the folder where It was suppose to store the image and didn't find the image.